# We need a java servlet that will export all workitems for a project and type in an excel in polarion

Tags: polarion

We need a java servlet that will export all workitems for a project and type (project.id: AND created:[20220301 TO $today-2d$])in an excel in polarion.
i need to do a compare of the existing workitems and new items that will be created using a new excel to find duplicate record before importing o new excel and creating new workitems.

Tried to get project but not the list of workitems in excel.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;

import com.polarion.alm.projects.IProjectService;
import com.polarion.alm.projects.model.IProject;
import com.polarion.alm.tracker.ITrackerService;
import com.polarion.alm.tracker.model.IWorkItem;
import com.polarion.platform.ITransactionService;
import com.polarion.platform.core.PlatformContext;
import com.polarion.platform.persistence.IDataService;
import com.polarion.platform.persistence.spi.PObject;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ITransactionService transactionService;
    private IDataService dataService;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // load properties from disk, do be used by subsequent calls
        transactionService = PlatformContext.getPlatform().lookupService(ITransactionService.class);
        dataService = PlatformContext.getPlatform().lookupService(IDataService.class);
    }

    public void getProjectWorkItem() {

        IProjectService projectService = (IProjectService) PlatformContext.getPlatform()
                .lookupService(IProjectService.class);
        ITrackerService trackerService = (ITrackerService) PlatformContext.getPlatform()
                .lookupService(ITrackerService.class);

        List<IProject> projects = projectService.searchProjects("mytest");
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(projects)) {
            // IProject projectSingle = projects.get(0).getId();
            IWorkItem workItem = trackerService.findWorkItem("mytest", "task");
            System.out.println("workItem");
        }

        System.out.println("workItem");
    }

}
```

Comment: Polarion Supports Excel export in Table view.. so what is the servlet for?

Comment: we need to compare the workitems for duplicates (all fields comparison) . once we import the excel we need to perform the duplicate check

Comment: You want to use an excel _ex_port or _im_port?